# Shell Script, sh only - no bash - Trying to add associative value with integer - "expr: non-numeric argument"

Tags: arrays, shell, sh

Hi I'm trying to add two values together, one which is an input from a file and another is a previous stored value in an associative array.

example of associative array:

moo -> 56

boo -> 34

foo -> 57

moo -> 45

I have all the code to detect wither the associative array value previously exists, but when I attempt to add them to the current value of the same key I receive an "expr: non-numeric argument" error.

This is the line I am using to add the two values:

```
c=`expr $i + eval $a$b`
```

Comment: The string "eval" certainly looks non-numeric, and since you are passing that string as an argument to `expr`, `expr` is rightly complaining about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sh` does not have associative arrays. If you have implemented your own, you have to specify how you did that.

Let's say you did it through a prefix and key, e.g. `arr_moo=56`:

```
i=4
arr_moo=56
a=arr_
b=moo
```

and given `i`, `a` and `b` you want to add the values of `i` and `arr_moo`, you can use:

```
c=$((i + $a$b))
echo "$c"
```

which will print `60`.